# Trouble with YahooFinanceAPI NuGet Package in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, yahoo-finance

I'm having trouble using YahooFinanceAPI NuGet Package.
I'm trying to get historical Data using this package, for now I have a window where the user can put some information, and after clicking on a button I would like to display the historical price in a List View.
The procedur when cliking the button is :

```
private async void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable Histo = new DataTable();
            foreach (string s in ListCol)
            {
                DataColumn x = new DataColumn();
                x.ColumnName = s;
                x.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                Histo.Columns.Add(x);
            }
            Symbol = "^FCHI";// Ticker.Text;
            StartDate = "21/02/2021";// DD.Text;
            EndDate = "21/02/2022"; //DF.Text;
            //Histo = DataFromYahoo.GetData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate);
            var awaiter = DataFromYahoo.ReceiveData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate, Histo);
            if (awaiter.Result == 1)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in Histo.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in Histo.Columns)
                    {
                        YahooData.Items.Add(row[col].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This part :

```
var awaiter = DataFromYahoo.ReceiveData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate, Histo);
```

comes from a DLL that I created :

```
public async Task<int> ReceiveData (string Symbol, string DD, string DF, DataTable Result)
        {
            DateTime StartDate;
            DateTime EndDate;
            StartDate = ConvertDate(DD);
            EndDate = ConvertDate(DF);
            var histo = await Yahoo.GetHistoricalAsync(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate,Period.Daily);
            DataRow row;
            foreach (var candle in histo)
            {
                row = Result.NewRow();
                row["Date"] = candle.DateTime.Date.ToString();
                row["Open"] = candle.Open.ToString();
                row["High"] = candle.High.ToString();
                row["Low"] = candle.Low.ToString();
                row["Close"] = candle.Close.ToString();
                row["AdjClos"] = candle.AdjustedClose.ToString();
                row["Volume"] = candle.Volume.ToString();
                Result.Rows.Add(row);

            }
            return 1;
        }
```

But when the code reach the part :

```
var histo = await Yahoo.GetHistoricalAsync(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate,Period.Daily);
```

It stop without any exception or error message.

I get this part from [here](https://github.com/karlwancl/YahooFinanceApi/blob/master/README.md)

And I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm also new in C# and I'm didn't really understood how works the async method, so if someone has some answer for me I will be glad.
Thanks !

EDIT : Also the ConvertDate() function will just convert date from a string format to a DateTime format as it's use in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await your async method:

```
private async void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable Histo = new DataTable();
    foreach (string s in ListCol)
    {
        DataColumn x = new DataColumn();
        x.ColumnName = s;
        x.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        Histo.Columns.Add(x);
    }
    Symbol = "^FCHI";// Ticker.Text;
    StartDate = "21/02/2021";// DD.Text;
    EndDate = "21/02/2022"; //DF.Text;
                            //Histo = DataFromYahoo.GetData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate);
    var awaiter = await DataFromYahoo.ReceiveData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate, Histo);
    if (awaiter == 1)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in Histo.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in Histo.Columns)
            {
                YahooData.Items.Add(row[col].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"Abusing" asynchronous code by for example accessing the blocking `.Result` property may deadlock which is probably what you have encountered here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to remove .Result but when I do that I have a compiler error : operator '==' cannot be applied to operand 'Task<int> and 'int'..

Comment: Then you forgot the `await` operator in front of `DataFromYahoo.ReceiveData`. Please read the answer once again and maybe just copy and paste it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer you but you were right. It worked perfectly thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use the yahoo api (they still support calling it). I use it. See below sample function to get historical data

```js
public StringBuilder FetchStockDataOnline(string scriptname, string range, string interval, string indicators = "quote", bool includeTimestamps = true)
        {
            StringBuilder returnData = null;
            string webservice_url = "";
            WebResponse wr;
            Stream receiveStream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                //https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/HDFC.BO?range=2yr&interval=1d&indicators=quote&includeTimestamps=true
                webservice_url = string.Format(StockManager.urlGetStockData, scriptname, range, interval, indicators, includeTimestamps);

                Uri url = new Uri(webservice_url);
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                wr = webRequest.GetResponseAsync().Result;
                receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                returnData = new StringBuilder(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return returnData;
        }
```